# How to find if 2 items are next to each other in a python tuple?

Tags: python

I have a tuple ("apple",pear","banana","watermelon") and want to find whether "pear","banana" are next to each other in this tuple.

May I know how to do it in python?

Comment: compare their indexes?

Comment: Hi. This site is about helping people with specific coding problems, not writing code for them. If you can attempt to solve the problem, but get stuck, we can help you out. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can use a small generator comprehension:

```
t = ("apple", "pear", "banana", "watermelon")

match = set(('pear', 'banana'))
any(match == set((t[i],t[i+1])) for i in range(len(t)-1))
```

output: `True`

**How it works:** the generator expression makes couples of consecutive values and compares them to the match set (sets are used as they are unordered). Then `any` will return `True` for the first `True` value. The advantage of using a generator is that the process will stop at the first match.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say this is the tuple:

```
tup = ("apple", "pear", "banana", "watermelon", "mango", "grapes")
```

Try zipping the tuple to check consecutive elements:

```
print(
    any(lhs == "pear" and rhs == "banana" for lhs, rhs in zip(tup, tup[1:]))
)
print(
    any(lhs == "pear" and rhs == "watermelon" for lhs, rhs in zip(tup, tup[1:]))
)
print(
    any(lhs == "watermelon" and rhs == "mango" for lhs, rhs in zip(tup, tup[1:]))
)
```

Or try using `functools.reduce`

```
from functools import reduce

print(
    reduce(
        lambda lhs, rhs: True if lhs is True or lhs == "pear" and rhs == "banana" else rhs,
        tup + (False,),
    )
)
print(
    reduce(
        lambda lhs, rhs: True if lhs is True or lhs == "pear" and rhs == "watermelon" else rhs,
        tup + (False,),
    )
)
print(
    reduce(
        lambda lhs, rhs: True if lhs is True or lhs == "watermelon" and rhs == "mango" else rhs,
        tup + (False,),
    )
)
```

**Output**

```
True
False
True
```

Answer (score 0):

A very analytical way of thinking about this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

tup = ("apple", "pear", "banana", "watermelon")

index = 0
pearIndex = 0
bananaIndex = 0
for item in tup:
   # print(item)
    if(item == 'pear'):
        pearIndex = index
    elif(item == 'banana'):
        bananaIndex = index
    index += 1

if(bananaIndex-pearIndex == 1 or pearIndex-bananaIndex == 1):
    print('they are next to each other')
```

Also your tuple is not right, it's missing some quotes before pear.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this would be to check if their absolute index difference is equal to 1.

Here's the code

```
tup = ("apple", "pear", "banana", "watermelon")
print(abs(tup.index("pear")-tup.index("banana")) == 1)
```

Comment: that wouldn't work in some cases if there are duplicate values though: `tup = ("banana", "watermelon", "apple", "pear", "banana")` would return `False` even if there is a matching combination